# How to find files in a directory which are older than 5 minutes, list them in a file, and also run the function every 15 mints to perform the task?

Tags: python

```
import sys
import os
import boto3
import time

FileDir="/Users/chandha/scripts/python/"
obj_FileDir = os.scandir(FileDir)

def validate_file_status():
  obj_FileDir = os.scandir(FileDir)
  for entry in obj_FileDir:
       age = time.time() - entry.stat().st_mtime
       if (entry.is_file()) and (age > 300):
          print(os.path.join(obj_FileDir,entry.name),age) 
      /* print a file name with created date and time and also age of the file */
  obj_FileDir.close()
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking. Does the code you posted work? Are you asking how to run every 15 mins?

Comment: Hi, Above code doesn't given any output unfortunately. I wanted to find a files from a given directory and list its in a file with age of file. And also wanted to run a function/code every 15 minutes for the files which are older than 5 mints

Comment: The code you posted only defines the function, but it's never called.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs some work to run:

- comments in python use # not /*
- you have defined a function but not called it
- stylistic: using a "with" clause is cleaner than open and closing objects
- stylistic (not fixed) variables in python tend to be snake_case (FileDir is PascalCase, obj_FileDir is a mixture of snake_PascalCase)

```py
import os
import time

# here we define the function
def validate_file_status(directory):
  with os.scandir(directory) as obj_FileDir:
      for entry in obj_FileDir:
           age = time.time() - entry.stat().st_mtime
           if (entry.is_file()) and (age > 300):
               # print a file name with created date and time and also age of the file
              print(os.path.join(directory, entry.name),age)
```

To run the function once:

```py
FileDir="/Users/chandha/scripts/python/"
validate_file_status(FileDir)
```

To make this code run every 15 minutes you can add a sleep:

```py
FileDir = "/Users/chandha/scripts/python/"
while true:  # only end when you kill the program (ctrl + C)
    validate_file_status(FileDir)
    time.sleep(15*60)  # sleep for 15 mins
```

Comment: Thanks. I received a below error   - validate_file_status(FileDir)
  File "FilesLockAlert.py", line 12, in validate_file_status
    print(os.path.join(obj_FileDir,entry.name),age)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ntpath.py", line 76, in join
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not nt.ScandirIterator

Comment: fixed now, sorry I tested locally but changed variable names when writing the solution

Comment: Your inputs are much appreciated. Now I'm able to list out the files which are older than 5 mints. But code failed to run every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Consider separating your concerns by making the script simpler and more focused on finding old files and utilizing something else, such as `cron` to handle the scheduling to run the script every 15 minutes.

Simplified script:

```
import os
import sys
import time


def find_old_files(directory_path: str, minutes: int) -> None:
  """Prints files in the specified directory that are older than the given number of minutes."""
  cutoff_time = time.time() - minutes * 60
  for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
    file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path) and os.path.getmtime(file_path) < cutoff_time:
      print(file_path)


def main() -> None:
  if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Usage: python3 find_old_files.py /path/to/directory minutes")
    sys.exit(1)
  directory_path = sys.argv[1]
  if not os.path.isdir(directory_path):
    print(f"Error: {directory_path} is not a valid directory.")
    sys.exit(1)
  minutes = int(sys.argv[2])
  find_old_files(directory_path, minutes)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Here's how you would schedule a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job on GNU/Linux/macOS/potentially Windows via WSL to run the script every 15 minutes:

1. Enter `crontab -e` in a terminal.
2. In file that opens enter a line like:

   ```
   */15 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/find_old_files.py /path/to/directory 5 >> /path/to/output_file.txt
   ```

   Make sure to replace `/usr/bin/python3`, `/path/to/find_old_files.py`, `/path/to/directory`, and `/path/to/output_file.txt` with the correct paths, before saving the file.